# ERROR: Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT (While append the element in the Array)

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, xcode6

When i try to append the element in the Array the error is shown.Here is the code.

```
func saveRecentSearch()  {
        var dictSearch = [String:Any]()
        if let onJourney = Global.onWordJ {
            dictSearch["From"] = onJourney.source
            dictSearch["Fromid"] = Global.onWordJ?.source?.CM_CityID
            dictSearch["To"] = Global.onWordJ?.destination
            dictSearch["Toid"] = Global.onWordJ?.destination?.CM_CityID
        }
        if let onJourney = Global.returnJ {
            dictSearch["todate"] = onJourney.journeyDate!
        }
        var arr = [[String:Any]]()
        if let arrSearch = UserDefault["Search"] {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                arr.append(arrSearch as! [String : Any])
                arr.append(dictSearch)
            }
        } else {
            arr.append(dictSearch)
        }
        UserDefault["Search"] = arr
    }
```

And i call this function in my `cellForRowAt indexPath` `tableView` method.

Comment: What is `UserDefault`?

Comment: UserDefaults.Standard

Comment: Show the code where you store the dictionary for "Search" key in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Why do you call this function in `cellForRow`? `cellForRow` is called very frequently and the function is not related to any `indexPath`. So the same code is executed many many times. That's pretty inefficient.

Comment: ok. I change that sorry for that. But what is the reason of the error?

Comment: Which line is giving the error?  (If it's the one containing `as!`, put a breakpoint there and show us the actual type of `arrSearch`.)

Comment: `arr.append(arrSearch as! [String : Any])` In this line

Comment: `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x1113b6050) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1113b4818)` This error is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have shown the error message already in the question. The error is pretty clear.

The value for key `Search` is an **array** so the forced cast `as! [String : Any]` to a **dictionary** fails.

Change the code to

```
...
var arr = [[String:Any]]()
if let arrSearch = UserDefault["Search"] as? [[String : Any]] {
   arr.append(contentsOf: arrSearch)
}
arr.append(dictSearch)
UserDefault["Search"] = arr
...
```

Dispatching to the main thread and the `else` clause is not needed.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks you save my time. I face the same issue many times overtime I just solve it by trial and error method. Can you please explain me what you have done so far. Thanks again.

Comment: I **read** the error message. The collection types Array (index based) and Dictionary (key based) are different and not related to each other